# UNNEST expression references column products which is neither grouped nor aggregated at

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table structure

[image]

and this query:

```
select user_id,min(timestamp) as first_order_time,max(timestamp) as most_recent_order_time,count(1) as no_orders,
 (SELECT SUM((item_price - extra_discount_total) / IFNULL(exchange_rate,1)) FROM UNNEST(products)) AS sums
from `order` 
where parent_order_id is null
group by 1
having min(timestamp)<timestamp('2017-12-31') and max(timestamp)>timestamp('2018-01-01')
```

the second line has something wrong as it says:

> UNNEST expression references column products which is neither grouped
>   nor aggregated at [2:89]

`exchange_rate` is part of the order table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  user_id,
  MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS first_order_time,
  MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS most_recent_order_time,
  COUNT(1) AS no_orders,
 SUM((SELECT SUM((item_price - extra_discount_total) / IFNULL(exchange_rate,1)) 
  FROM UNNEST(products))
 ) AS sums
FROM `order` 
WHERE parent_order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
HAVING MIN(TIMESTAMP)<TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') AND MAX(TIMESTAMP)>TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01')
```

Comment: So just to understand. First we sum the multiple rows of the products, then the multiple rows based on user group by?

Comment: Correct. First we sum up values from repeated record of the given row and than we sum up with group by